# Replacing relations from one node to another by one single relation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have been pushing several times the same relationship between 2 nodes in Neo4j.
It was a mistake as it makes the visualization less clear.

Now, I would like to replace those several relations between 2 nodes by one single relation. It would be great if we could keep the number of relations inside a property "count" on the new unique relation.

What would be an efficient way to solve this problem ?
I have about 100 000 of relations and I am a bit worried about the time it would take.

Here is a quick example to make the problem clearer : 
I have :

```
Node A -- R1 -- Node B
Node A -- R2 -- Node B
```

And I would like to have

```
Node A -- R {count : 2} -- Node B
```

Thanks!

Comment: **I assume you want to run this over all the nodes in the database.** Do these relationships have any properties on them?

Comment: Does the direction of relationship matters to you? **What if there are X number of  relationships from node A to B, and Y number of relationships from node B to A?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I assume these relationships don't have any properties and Direction of the relationships doesn't matter.**

You can combine these relationships with Cypher Query as shown:

```
MATCH (p:Node)-[r]-(c:Node)
WHERE ID(p) > ID(c)
DELETE r
WITH p, c, COUNT(r) as count
CREATE (p)-[:R{count:count}]->(c)
```

If you want to merge relationships having the same directions only then you can use the following query:

```
MATCH (p:Node)-[r]->(c:Node)
DELETE r
WITH p, c, COUNT(r) as count
CREATE (p)-[newrel:R{count:count}]->(c)
```

> If you want to merge the properties as well then you can take help of
>   **[apoc plugin's](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#graph-refactoring)** `apoc.refactor.mergeRelationships` method.

Comment: You can check the example of apoc merge: https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#graph-refactoring

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I wanted.